# Oracle error 43914 in CASE WHEN expression: arguments have undefined collation

Tags: oracle, errors, case

I want to know which is the difference between this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TEST_TABLE 
WHERE CHAR_FIELD = CASE WHEN KEY_FIELD = 'Q' THEN 'M' 
                   ELSE CASE WHEN KEY_FIELD = 'T' THEN 'K' ELSE 
                              CHAR_FIELD2 END 
                   END;
```

And this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TEST_TABLE 
WHERE CHAR_FIELD = CASE WHEN KEY_FIELD = 'Q' THEN 'M' 
                        ELSE CASE WHEN KEY_FIELD <> 'T' THEN CHAR_FIELD2
                        ELSE 'K' END END;
```

I expect both queries to return same data in all cases but, first one gives me an ORA-43914 "unable to determine collation: arguments have undefined collation" error while second one works just fine.

I read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/nlspg/appendix-C-collation-derivation-and-determination-rules-for-SQL-operations.html#GUID-AFCE41ED-775B-4A00-AF38-C436776AE0C5) information about collation determination in Oracle but it's not clear to me how it works with case-when expression.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is your character set and national character set of your database?  Do either of them have áccënted characters?  I thought at first,  maybe the `<> 'T'` in the second query could be causing issues, but you say that query works?

Comment: And what are the data types of `KEY_FIELD` and `CHAR_FIELD2`?